# CodeIgniter: Issue loading table in view

Tags: php, codeigniter

Very simple stuff here, I'm new to CI. I have the following:

**Model**

```
 class Stockists_model extends CI_Model {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();  
    }

    function stockists_all() {
        return $this->db->get('stockists')->result();
    }
 }
```

**Controller**

```
    $data['stockists'] = $this->Stockists_model->stockists_all();
    $this->load->view($this->data['system_settings']['admin_folder']  .'/stockists', $this->data);
```

**View**

```
foreach($stockists as $stockist) {
    echo $stockist->Shp_num_an;
    echo $stockist->Postcode;
}
```

But I get the error:

> Undefined variable: stockists

and

> Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Can anyone see an issue here?

Comment: Do you have data in your table??? and use `!empty($stockists)` in view before `foreach loop`

Comment: can you please do in your view var_dump($stockists) and post your results here?

Comment: which line display the Undefined variable: stockists error ?

Comment: Stockists is empty, this seems to be the issue. If I do an 'if $stockists has has value) I get: "Undefined variable: stockists"

Comment: `$this->data` this should be  `$data`

Comment: `$this->load->view($this->data['system_settings']['admin_folder']  .'/stockists', $data);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you are getting your data in `$data['stocklists]` then
send data to page by

```
$this->load->view($this->data['system_settings']['admin_folder']  .'/stockists',array('data'=>$data));
```

and on other page retreive data from array by

```
$stocklists=$data['stocklists'];
```

It will work if you are having table in `$data['stocklists']`

Good Luck!!